# "How important is education to children's future?"

Tags: sentence-construction

> How important is education to children's future?

Does this sentence sound natural to you?

Comment: does it to you? what's the context? I'm afraid this question is about 'proofreading'. Please enter some more detail

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> How important is education to **a child's** future?

This could refer to an individual child or children in general.

If you want to use plural *children*, then you would have to write *childrens' futures*, but this sounds odd at best.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how it could have specific reference.  I can only come up with the general reading.

Comment: @snailplane Indefinite article "a" means it could be any child (as opposed to "my" child). Since each child's future will be different, the statement would be referring to any (one) child's future at a time. Maybe my use of "general" was inappropriate. To me it is more of a logical rather than technical distinction.